# Django: Making additional REST call inside View when handling user's form

Tags: django, django-views

What do I have: One Django form with a set of fields users can populate and send.
When I handle form fields into View Class one additional Http request should be executed (to external Rest service) to check the user's address and add coordinates.

So in plain Python this may be done with

```
import requests
requests.get()
```

How this case should be implemented in Django?

Comment: Just like that. Clean form data and make the request

Comment: hm ))) yeah it was as simple as it is. I've imported requests and made the requests after form cleaned

It works , but sometimes requires a sensitive time delay in UI, probably adding progress bar is a good idea

Comment: It takes time yeah depending on the request itself, but its fine if it doesn't cross 20 seconds, maximum 30, because at this point some workers in the host will shut down for example heroku